# Passing multiple arguments to SOAP webservice using SUDS

Tags: python, soap

There is a PHP SOAP webservice I want to use, that requires authentication. However username and password are not required to be passed in HTTP header but as SOAP arguments. I only have a PHP (working) example of running a query:

```
$soap_client->getCurrentOrderCustomers(array("user" => 'root', "password" => 'toor'));
```

This works fine and creates following request:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="https://example.com/webservice/interface_bi.php" xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:getCurrentOrderCustomers>
         <param0 xsi:type="ns2:Map">
            <item>
               <key xsi:type="xsd:string">user</key>
               <value xsi:type="xsd:string">root</value>
            </item>
            <item>
               <key xsi:type="xsd:string">password</key>
               <value xsi:type="xsd:string">toor</value>
            </item>
         </param0>
      </ns1:getCurrentOrderCustomers>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Assuming the client is created properly (it is), I tried following in Python:

```
result = ws_client.service.getCurrentOrderCustomers({'user':'root','password':'toor'})
```

And this as well:

```
result = ws_client.service.getCurrentOrderCustomers(user='root',password='toor')
```

However both of them lead to following request, with no arguments:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns2="https://example.com/webservice/interface_bi.php" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <ns1:Body>
      <ns2:getCurrentOrderCustomers/>
   </ns1:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I would be very grateful if someone suggested how to pass arguments to webservice function in order to get desired request. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think - the SOAP service WSDL tells us how to pass parameters to SOAP method.
I tried following following code Python and SOAP call using suds works fine for me.

Line number 4 - print client shows all the soap methods with parameters

```
from suds.client import Client

url="http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?wsdl"
client = Client(url)

print client ## shows the details of this service

result = client.service.Multiply(10, 5)
print result
```

Following is the output from above script

[image: Output of Python Soap Call]

@[Pawel Sopel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1642127/pawe%C5%82-sopel)
 - If you share your WSDL, I can further investigate.